# Error when generate mobile_number in Django-seed

Tags: python, django, attributeerror, phone-number, seed

I tried to generate a fake phone number with `Django-seed`:

here is the function that creates my seed

```
def create_users():
  seeder = Seed.seeder()
  seeder.add_entity(User, 4, {
    'mobile_number': PhoneNumber.from_string("+41 79 123 45 67"),
    'email': lambda x: seeder.fake.email(),
    'is_superuser': False,
    'is_staff': False,
    'is_active': True,
  })
  seeder.execute()
```

I also tried this: `'mobile_number': "+43 79 123 XX XX"`

Whatever i try i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../pycharm/django_manage.py", line 59, in <module>
    run_command()
  File ".../pycharm/django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File ".../manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File ".../event_manager/management/commands/seed.py", line 21, in handle
    run_seed(self, options['mode'])
  File ".../event_manager/management/commands/seed.py", line 36, in run_seed
    create_users()
  File ".../event_manager/management/commands/seed.py", line 57, in create_users
    'is_active': True,
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_seed/seeder.py", line 132, in add_entity
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django_seed/seeder.py", line 60, in guess_field_formatters
    formatter = field_type_guesser.guess_format(field)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django_seed/guessers.py", line 107, in guess_format
    raise AttributeError(field)
AttributeError: users.User.mobile_number
```

Here is the user model:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(_("Mobile phone number"), blank=True, null=True, help_text=_("International format with country code (starting with \"+\"). Ex. +43 71 123 45 XX."))
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing ?

Comment: Please add the full error stacktrace, so we can see which line raises the error

Comment: @Ralf, i add the full erro

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because `mobile_number` is not a field of the model `User` (at least not in the default django User model); the error is in this part of your code:

```
seeder.add_entity(User, 4, {
    'mobile_number': ...,
    ...
})
```

You need to specify another model that has that field, or change/remove the field `mobile_number` from your call to `seeder.add_entity()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my User model is not the default model of django. @Ralf